# When using Apache Curator, why does creating a zNode cause NoNodeException

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am trying to create a "directory" in Zookeeper like this:

```
curatorFramework = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(
    "ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181",
    zkInfo.getSessionTimeoutMs(),
    zkInfo.getConnectionTimeoutMs(),
    new RetryNTimes(zkInfo.getRetryAttempts(), 
    zkInfo.getRetryIntervalMs())
);
curatorFramework.start();

byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
byteArray[0] = (byte) 7;

curatorFramework.create()
    .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
    .withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
    .forPath("/my_node", byteArray);
```

Perplexingly, it is giving me a "NoNodeException" on the very node I'm trying to create.

```
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /my_node
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1176) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1156) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1153) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:607) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:597) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:362) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:310) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

Note that I am able to connect to Zookeeper:

```
Socket connection established to ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181, initiating session
Session establishment complete on server ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181, sessionid = 0x100000363b13354, negotiated timeout = 20000
```

Please note that the Zookeeper server is on a remote machine and the ip ("111.11.111.1") has been changed in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to ACLs, just to be sure, you could manually create it.

Locate your local zk binaries (doesn't need to be on the remote host) and launch the client (`zkCli`) pointing at your server. Once connected, create the new znode:

```
bin/zkCli.sh -server 111.11.111.1:2181

[zkshell:x] create /my_node
>>Created /mynode
```

The shell should output the last sentence in order to guarantee the node has been created. Once done, launch again the Curator process.

Take a look [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html) for more detailed info about the zk client.

Answer (score 2):

So I tried connecting with zkCli and found that it was my connectString that was the problem:

```
/opt/zookeeper-3.6.1/bin/zkCli.sh -server ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
[myid:ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1154] - Opening socket connection to server ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181.
[myid:ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@986] - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /111.11.111.2:43736, server: ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181
[myid:ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1420] - Session establishment complete on server ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181, session id = 0x100000363b1d2e8, negotiated timeout = 30000

[zk: ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
Node does not exist: /
[zk: ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181(CONNECTED) 1] create /my_node
Node does not exist: /my_node
```

As you can see, trying to create a node gives you a NoNode error in zkCli.

It turns out that `ip-111-11-111-1.us-west-2.compute.internal/111.11.111.1:2181` was not a correct connect string, but I was confused because zkCli allowed me to connect to it.

Comment: well that's a lucky shot indeed : P

Comment: Yes, it's weird that Zookeeper is able to establish a connection with a supposedly invalid connect string. It's still unclear to me what the specification  of connectString is. Anyways, thanks for the help.